# Sentence segmentation and dependency parser

Tags: spacy

I’m pretty new to python (using python 3) and spacy (and programming too). Please bear with me.

I have three questions where two are more or less the same I just can’t get it to work.
I took the “syntax specific search with spacy” ([example](https://gist.github.com/honnibal/30499850449a46c167a8)) and tried to make different things work.

My program currently reads txt and the normal extraction

```
if w.lower_ != 'music':
return False
```

works.

My first question is: How can I get spacy to extract two words?
For example: “classical music”
With the previous mentioned snippet I can make it extract either classical or music. But if I only search for one of the words I also get results I don’t want like.

Classical – period / era

Or when I look for only music

Music – baroque, modern

The second question is: How can I get the dependencies to work?

The example dependency with:

```
elif w.dep_ != 'nsubj': # Is it the subject of a verb?
return False
```

works fine. But everything else I tried does not really work.

For example, I want to extract sentences with the word “birthday” and the dependency ‘DATE’. (so the dependency is an entity)

I got

```
if d.ent_type_ != ‘DATE’:
return False
```

To work.

So now it would look like:

```
def extract_information(w,d):
if w.lower_ != ‘birthday’:
return False
elif d.ent_type_ != ‘DATE’:
return False
else:
return True
```

Does something like this even work?

If it works the third question would be how I can filter sentences for example with a DATE. So If the sentence contains a certain word and a DATE exclude it.

Last thing maybe, I read somewhere that the dependencies are based on the “Stanford typed dependencies manual”. Is there a list which of those dependencies work with spacy?

Thank you for your patience and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Before I get into offering some simple suggestions to your questions, have you tried using displaCy's [visualiser](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/) on some of your sentences?

Using an example sentence 'John's birthday was yesterday', you'll find that within the parsed sentence, birthday and yesterday are not necessarily direct dependencies of one another. So searching based on the birthday word having a dependency of a DATE type entity, might not be yield the best of results.

Onto the first question:
A brute force method would be to look for matching *subsequent* words after you have parsed the sentence.

```
doc = nlp(u'Mary enjoys classical music.')

for (i,token) in enumerate(doc):
    if (token.lower_ == 'classical') and (i != len(doc)-1):             
        if doc[i+1].lower_ == 'music':
            print 'Target Acquired!'
```

If you're unsure of what enumerate does, look it up. It's the pythonic way of using python.

To questions 2 and 3, one simple (but not elegant) way of solving this is to just identify in a parsed sentence if the word 'birthday' exists and if it contains an entity of type 'DATE'.

```
doc = nlp(u'John\'s birthday was yesterday.')

for token in doc:
    if token.lower_ == 'birthday':
        for entities in doc.ents:
            if entities.label_ == 'DATE':
                print 'Found ya!'
```

As for the list of dependencies, I presume you're referring to the Part-Of-Speech tags. Check out the documentation on this [page](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/pos-tagging).

Good luck! Hope that helped.

Comment: thank you for the fast help i only now had time to test it. The displacy visualiser was a good tip that showed me that my understanding of a sentence is not like spacys :) i tried your methods and they work on their own. meaning: i cant get them to work in my program (sorry)
the DATE command unfortunatly does not connect with the previous statement so instead it lists me all found dates. do you know how to fix that?
secondly my print command is 'for word in document_read:
  if extract_information(word):print(''.join(w.string for w in word.head.subtree).strip())'

Comment: and i get the error message 'extract_information() missing 1 required positional argument'. understandable because we used i as a second argument. but if i include the i -> 'extract_information(word,i)' i get the error message 'name 'i' is not defined' also understandable but i don't know how to define it and include it in the 'print(''.join(w.string for w in word.head.subtree).strip()'.
i am currently trying to fix it so i will update if i got it on my own. thanks again!

Comment: @My3vilMe could you share/explain the whole process that you're trying to achieve? I'm having difficulty understanding what you're after in the two comments above. Perhaps also provide an example indicating your desired output for an example sentence.